# Error when installing Scrapy with pip on Mac

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I run `pip install Scrapy` and everything seems to download fine, but installation ultimately fails.

Is there some sort of an issue with permissions? I'm a novice, so any help much appreciated!

Abridged terminal output:

```
...    

running install_egg_info

running egg_info

writing requirements to Scrapy.egg-info/requires.txt

writing Scrapy.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Scrapy.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Scrapy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


reading manifest file 'Scrapy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'

writing manifest file 'Scrapy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

Copying Scrapy.egg-info to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg-info

running install_scripts

copying build/scripts-2.7/scrapy -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin

error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/scrapy: Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/pavelfage/build/Scrapy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/x6/wf5kq24j109dnkhgjcs822ym0000gn/T/pip-QgV9nv-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
```

Comment: This occurs with several libraries that need root permissions. Just prepend `sudo` to your command and enter your root password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write in /Library/Frameworks/* use `sudo pip install scrapy`

If doing using virtual environment, first activate the environment and then install

```
 $ . /path/to/venv/bin/activate
 $ pip install scrapy
```